# El método "strftime" aplicado a una variable del tipo "DateTime", cambia su tipo a "object"?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter

La importación de cotizaciones desde **yfinance**, devuelve el siguiente DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

def import_data(ticker, start_date, end_date):
    df = yf.download(ticker, start=start_date, end=end_date, progress=False)
    df_close = df[['Close']].copy(deep=True)
    return df, df_close

# Definir los parámetros
ticker = '^IBEX'
start_date = '2010-01-04'
end_date = '2019-10-28'

# Importar los datos
df_closes, df_close = import_data(ticker, start_date, end_date) 

# Imprimir la información del DataFrame con el nuevo formato de fechas
df_closes.info()
```

Devuelve :

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 2510 entries, 2010-01-04 00:00:00+01:00 to 2019-10-25 00:00:00+02:00
Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------     --------------  -----  
 0   Open       2510 non-null   float64
 1   High       2510 non-null   float64
 2   Low        2510 non-null   float64
 3   Close      2510 non-null   float64
 4   Adj Close  2510 non-null   float64
 5   Volume     2510 non-null   int64  
dtypes: float64(5), int64(1)
memory usage: 137.3 KB
None
```

Vemos que el índice es del tipo **DatetimeIndex**.
Quiero cambiar el formato de las fechas de este índice de filas para que sean **YY-MM-DD, para lo que hago.

**df_closes.index = df_closes.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')**

Me devuelve.

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 2510 entries, 2010-01-04 to 2019-10-25
Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------     --------------  -----  
 0   Open       2510 non-null   float64
 1   High       2510 non-null   float64
 2   Low        2510 non-null   float64
 3   Close      2510 non-null   float64
 4   Adj Close  2510 non-null   float64
 5   Volume     2510 non-null   int64  
dtypes: float64(5), int64(1)
memory usage: 137.3+ KB
```

Las fechas ya tienen el nuevo formato, pero ¿Ha cambiado el tipo y ya no son **DateTime**

Si es así, ¿cómo puedo cambiar el formato de las fechas de dicho índice sin que dejen de ser del tipo **DateTime**
Agradeceré ayuda

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el código de un `DataFrame` como el que muestras pero que no dependa de recursos externos así podemos probarlo? Creo que [esto](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format_index.html) podría ser útil pero no tengo como probarlo.

Comment: Generalmente, el formato de la fecha no es importante a la hora de trabajar con ella, si no que es algo puramente estetico. Por que no trabajás con la fecha sin darle formato y luego, cuando quieras mostrar el df, le das formato?